# Office365 Password-Prompt once a day

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

We have installed Office365 (with hosted Exchange and AD-Sync) on a client's network. Some of them experience a weird behaviour of outlook. The user arrives at this desk, boots up his computer and starts outlook. Then he gets prompted for a password. He puts it in and it works. The next day it happens again.

We tried closing outlook and restarting it -> didn't ask for password.

We tried rebooting the computer -> didn't ask for password.

Clearing out the Credential Manager or disabling cached mode didn't help. Any ideas what the source of this problem could be? My google-fu only found one other topic with this kind of behaviour (once a day prompts) and that was on ESET forum with no solution. We use ESET too, but the problem exists before we switched the client from Kaspersky to ESET.

I cannot change his authentification type in his settings. The option doesn't exist in his outlook. I thought it might use Kerberos and after 10 hours (max duration of a ticket) it would prompt again for a password.

Clients uses Windows 10 64-bit with Outlook 2016.

Comment: As far as I know, if Outlook anywhere is configured to use Basic authentication, it must prompt for credential one time when users launch Outlook. The authentication option doesn't show in Outlook 2016 now. You have to contact admin to check this setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried a different set of approaches and it seems like I was a bit too hasty with the Exchange-Cache-Mode. When we first disabled it, then he got a different set of error-notifications, he said. I didn't go into details with him, when I should have.

The problem was fixed by disabling the Exchange-Cache-Mode in Outlook. We waited a few days and asked the customer again. He said no further password-prompts happened. Then enabled the Exchange-Cache-Mode in Outlook again and waited another couple of days. Still no password-prompts. I'm not sure whether the waiting-time between disabling and re-enabling is relevant here, but that's at least how I did it. I'm still a little confused on why this solved the problem, but right now I'm just happy that it did.